# How to get user id and access token of instagram account after the oct 15th update?

Tags: api, instagram, instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

In my Instagram developer account it is showing this:

> Starting October 15, 2019, new client registration and permission review on Instagram API platform are discontinued in favor of the Instagram Basic Display API.

So I don't know how to get user id and access token now. Could someone explain what are the ways to get user id and access token of the Instagram account.

I tried to get a Client ID but the new change in Instagram is not allowing further steps. I followed this article -> https://docs.oceanwp.org/article/487-how-to-get-instagram-access-token

It showing like this for every account. 
[View of account](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGXcH.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can find it here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/getting-started
But tokens are only valid for 1 hour now (((

Answer (score -1):

You can get the access token from this link.

Try it -> https://instagram.pixelunion.net/